# npm install ethereumjs-util on a raspberry pi

Tags: nodejs, ethereumjs, raspberry-pi

I am using a raspberry pi as an air-gapped computer. Web3 installs and works just fine on my pi. My problem is I need to get a public address from a private key and this requires ethereumjs-util which will not install on my raspberry pi.
I am using a pi 2 with raspbian. The following is the error log which as if by magic seems to be highlighting important parts.

Can someone please tell me what I need to do in order to install ethereumjs-util on a pi. Thanks, John

pi@raspberrypi:~/Transaction $ npm install ethereumjs-util --save
npm WARN package.json keypairs@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json keypairs@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json keypairs@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN engine ethjs-util@0.1.4: wanted: {"npm":">=3","node":">=6.5.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})
npm WARN engine keccak@1.3.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})
npm WARN engine secp256k1@3.3.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})
npm WARN engine strip-hex-prefix@1.0.0: wanted: {"npm":">=3","node":">=6.5.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})
npm WARN engine is-hex-prefixed@1.0.0: wanted: {"npm":">=3","node":">=6.5.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})
npm WARN engine deep-extend@0.4.2: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0","iojs":">=1.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})

> keccak@1.3.0 install /home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/keccak
>   prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild || echo "Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."

prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 2.1.2
prebuild-install info looking for local prebuild @ prebuilds/keccak-v1.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz
prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ /home/pi/.npm/_prebuilds/https-github.com-cryptocoinjs-keccak-releases-download-v1.3.0-keccak-v1.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz
prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/keccak/releases/download/v1.3.0/keccak-v1.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz
prebuild-install http 404 https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/keccak/releases/download/v1.3.0/keccak-v1.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=0.10.29 runtime=node arch=arm platform=linux)
make: Entering directory '/home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/keccak/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/keccak/src/addon.o
In file included from ../src/addon.cc:2:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:326:47: error: ‘REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’
   static const unsigned kReplaceInvalidUtf8 = v8::String::REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8;
                                               ^
keccak.target.mk:100: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/keccak/src/addon.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/keccak/src/addon.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/keccak/build'
ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.50-v7+
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/keccak
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used.

### npm WARN engine deep-extend@0.4.2: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0","iojs":">=1.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.29","npm":"1.4.21"})

> secp256k1@3.3.0 install /home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/secp256k1
>   prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild || echo "Secp256k1 bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."

prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 2.1.2
prebuild-install info looking for local prebuild @ prebuilds/secp256k1-v3.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz
prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ /home/pi/.npm/_prebuilds/https-github.com-cryptocoinjs-secp256k1-node-releases-download-v3.3.0-secp256k1-v3.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz
prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/secp256k1-node/releases/download/v3.3.0/secp256k1-v3.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz
prebuild-install http 404 https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/secp256k1-node/releases/download/v3.3.0/secp256k1-v3.3.0-node-v11-linux-arm.tar.gz
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=0.10.29 runtime=node arch=arm platform=linux)
make: Entering directory '/home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/secp256k1/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/addon.o
In file included from ../src/addon.cc:2:0:
../node_modules/nan/nan.h:326:47: error: ‘REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8’ is not a member of ‘v8::String’
   static const unsigned kReplaceInvalidUtf8 = v8::String::REPLACE_INVALID_UTF8;
                                               ^
secp256k1.target.mk:124: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/addon.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/secp256k1/src/addon.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/secp256k1/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.50-v7+
gyp ERR! command "nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/Transaction/node_modules/ethereumjs-util/node_modules/secp256k1
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Secp256k1 bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used.
ethereumjs-util@5.1.2 node_modules/ethereumjs-util
+-- rlp@2.0.0
+-- bn.js@4.11.6
+-- create-hash@1.1.3 (inherits@2.0.3, cipher-base@1.0.3, ripemd160@2.0.1, sha.js@2.4.8)
+-- ethjs-util@0.1.4 (is-hex-prefixed@1.0.0, strip-hex-prefix@1.0.0)
+-- keccak@1.3.0 (bindings@1.2.1, inherits@2.0.3, safe-buffer@5.1.0, nan@2.6.2, prebuild-install@2.1.2)
+-- secp256k1@3.3.0 (bindings@1.2.1, bip66@1.1.5, safe-buffer@5.1.0, drbg.js@1.0.1, nan@2.6.2, prebuild-install@2.1.2, elliptic@6.4.0)
+-- babelify@7.3.0 (object-assign@4.1.1, babel-core@6.25.0)
+-- babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1 (babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals@6.22.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring@6.23.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-duplicate-keys@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions@6.22.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs@6.24.1, babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants@6.22.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread@6.22.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions@6.22.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-unicode-regex@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-regenerator@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of@6.23.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd@6.24.1, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol@6.23.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals@6.22.0, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties@6.24.1)

Thanks again,
John

Comment: This question is answered at the following link https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68766/npm-install-ethereumjs-util-on-a-raspberry-pi